# Cast object to generic list where type T taken from variable

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting

```
var typeArgument = Type.GetType(mapping.TypeName);
var method = _dbAccessor.GetType()
                            .GetMethod("GetViewData")
                            .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeArgument });
var viewData = method.Invoke(_dbAccessor, new object[] { mapping.SourceName });
```

`GetViewData` is generic method. It get string data by `mapping.SourceName`, deserializes to List of typeArgument and returns `List<typeArgument>`.
viewData has type `object`. But I know that `viewData` is List of objects of type `typeArgument`.
So how could I cast object to `List<typeArgument>` to allow iteration by `foreach` for `var viewData`?

Comment: You can cast viewData to `System.Collections.IList` or `System.Collections.IEnumerable`.

Comment: you don't have direct access to GetViewData? why are you even using reflection?

Comment: And your question does not make sense at all. If you use reflection you loose type definition, everything is object. now casting does not make any sense

Comment: Since you don't know the type at compile time, casting is a nonsensical operation. See first marked duplicate. For enumeration, you can cast to a known non-generic interface. See second marked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It was i need. Into iterations I'll be able to get value by property name.

Answer (score 1):

Did I get that right? Variable `viewData` is an object but you know that it is a `List<SomeTypeHere>`?

Well, you could cast your `viewData` to `IEnumerable` to loop through it. But you won't be able to do anything good with it because you don't know the objects type:

```
foreach (object item in (viewData as IEnumerable))
{ 
}
```

However, if you know the items' type, you can use the extension method `OfType()`:

```
var castedObjects = (viewData as IEnumerable).OfType<SomeTypeHere>();
foreach (SomeTypeHere item in castedObjects )
{ 
}
```

Make sure to include the Linq namespace: `using System.Linq`

Comment: Now that the question has been edited, the first `foreach` shows a working solution. The second loop is not possible, though, because OP has no access to `SomeTypeHere` type.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use the list returned by the `Invoke` method in a strongly typed fashion if that's what you want.

Casting to `IEnumerable` is your best option if you simply want to be able iterate over it:

```
var viewData = method.Invoke(_dbAccessor, new object[] { mapping.SourceName }) as IEnumerable;
if(viewData != null)
    foreach (var data in viewData)
    {
        ...
    }
```

If you want to add something to the list you could cast to `IList`.

Please refer to the following blog post for more information.

**Generic type parameters and dynamic types in C#:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/10/31/generic-type-parameters-and-dynamic-types-in-csharp/